# Run time broker interrupting sleep

Tags: sleep

I noticed my HTPC wasn't going to sleep when it should.  I ran the system sleep diagnostics and found a few things sending power requests.

There was NVIDIA audio, svchost.exe and runtimebroker.exe  I've added them to requestsoverride and the NVIDIA and svchost no longer come up on the system sleep diagnostics.

Runtimebroker is still there though.  It's listed as system and execution.  You can't add the same program twice to a category in requestsoverride so I've added the system under service and the execution under process but it's still showing as sending a power request.

Does anyone have any idea how to set this properly in requestsoverride?

[image]

[image]